# Circular dependencies between generic types (CollectionType and its Index/Generator, e.g.)

Tags: swift, generics, protocols, persistent-storage

Given a `struct`-based generic `CollectionType` …

```
struct MyCollection<Element>: CollectionType, MyProtocol {
    typealias Index = MyIndex<MyCollection>

    subscript(i: Index) -> Element { … }

    func generate() -> IndexingGenerator<MyCollection> {
        return IndexingGenerator(self)
    }
}
```

… how would one define an `Index` for it …

```
struct MyIndex<Collection: MyProtocol>: BidirectionalIndexType {

    func predecessor() -> MyIndex { … }
    func successor() -> MyIndex { … }
}
```

… without introducing a dependency cycle of death?

The generic nature of `MyIndex` is necessary because:

1. It should work with any type of `MyProtocol`.
2. `MyProtocol` references `Self` and thus can only be used as a type constraint.

If there were forward declarations (à la Objective-C) I would *just*<sup>[sic!]</sup> add one for `MyIndex<MyCollection>` to my `MyCollection<…>`. Alas, there is no such thing.

---

A possible concrete use case would be binary trees, such as:

```
indirect enum BinaryTree<Element>: CollectionType, BinaryTreeType {
    typealias Index = BinaryTreeIndex<BinaryTree>

    case Nil
    case Node(BinaryTree, Element, BinaryTree)

    subscript(i: Index) -> Element { … }
}
```

Which would require a stack-based `Index`:

```
struct BinaryTreeIndex<BinaryTree: BinaryTreeType>: BidirectionalIndexType {
    let stack: [BinaryTree]

    func predecessor() -> BinaryTreeIndex { … }
    func successor() -> BinaryTreeIndex { … }
}
```

---

One cannot (yet?) nest `struct`s inside generic `struct`s in Swift.
Otherwise I'd just move `BinaryTreeIndex<…>` inside `BinaryTree<…>`.

Also I'd prefer to have one generic `BinaryTreeIndex`,
which'd then work with any type of `BinaryTreeType`.

Comment: Xcode 7 beta 4 introduced `indirect enum`, but I haven't heard of `indirect struct` yet. Did I miss something?

Comment: @MartinR: Nope, a typo. `indirect enum` it is of course. Good catch. ;)

Comment: What do you mean by "dependency cycle of death"?

Comment: @Qbyte: If you look at the snippets you'll notice that they're given each other as generic parameters. They're specialized on each other, making the compiler run in circles, like a cat chasing its own tail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While **Airspeed Velocity**'s answer applies to the most common cases, my question was asking specifically about the special case of generalizing `CollectionType` indexing in order to be able to share a single `Index` implementation for all thinkable kinds of binary trees (whose recursive nature makes it necessary to make use of a stack for index-based traversals (at least for trees without a parent pointer)), which requires the `Index` to be specialized on the actual `BinaryTree`, not the `Element`.

The way I solved this problem was to rename `MyCollection` to `MyCollectionStorage`, revoke its `CollectionType` conformity and wrap it with a struct that now takes its place as `MyCollection` and deals with conforming to `CollectionType`.

To make things a bit more "real" I will refer to:

- `MyCollection<E>` as `SortedSet<E>`
- `MyCollectionStorage<E>` as `BinaryTree<E>`
- `MyIndex<T>` as `BinaryTreeIndex<T>`

So without further ado:

```
struct SortedSet<Element>: CollectionType {
    typealias Tree = BinaryTree<Element>
    typealias Index = BinaryTreeIndex<Tree>

    subscript(i: Index) -> Element { … }

    func generate() -> IndexingGenerator<SortedSet> {
        return IndexingGenerator(self)
    }
}

struct BinaryTree<Element>: BinaryTreeType {

}

struct BinaryTreeIndex<BinaryTree: BinaryTreeType>: BidirectionalIndexType {
    func predecessor() -> BinaryTreeIndex { … }
    func successor() -> BinaryTreeIndex { … }
}
```

This way the dependency graph turns from a **directed cyclic graph** into a **directed acyclic graph**.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot nest structs inside structs because they are value types. They aren’t pointers to an object, instead they hold their properties right there in the variable. Think about if a struct contained itself, what would its memory layout look like?

Forward declarations work in Objective-C because they are then used as *pointers*. This is why the `indirect` keyword was added to enums - it tells the compiler to add a level of indirection via a pointer.

In theory the same keyword could be added to structs, but it wouldn’t make much sense. You could do what `indirect` does by hand instead though, with a class box:

```
// turns any type T into a reference type
final class Box<T> {
    let unbox: T
    init(_ x: T) { unbox = x }
}
```

You could the use this to box up a struct to create, e.g., a linked list:

```
struct ListNode<T> {
    var box: Box<(element: T, next: ListNode<T>)>?

    func cons(x: T) -> ListNode<T> {
        return ListNode(node: Box(element: x, next: self))
    }

    init() { box = nil }
    init(node: Box<(element: T, next: ListNode<T>)>?)
    { box = node }
}

let nodes = ListNode().cons(1).cons(2).cons(3)
nodes.box?.unbox.element // first element
nodes.box?.unbox.next.box?.unbox.element // second element
```

You *could* turn this node directly into a collection, by conforming it to both `ForwardIndexType` and `CollectionType`, but this isn’t a good idea.

For example, they need very different implementations of `==`:

- the index needs to know if two indices from the same list are at the same position. It does not need the elements to conform to `Equatable`.
- The collection needs to compare two different collections to see if they hold the same elements. It *does* need the elements to conform to `Equatable` i.e.:

  ```
  func == <T where T: Equatable>(lhs: List<T>, rhs: List<T>) -> Bool {
      // once the List conforms to at least SequenceType:
      return lhs.elementsEqual(rhs)
  }
  ```

Better to wrap it in two specific types. This is “free” – the wrappers have no overhead, just help you build the right behaviours more easily:

```
struct ListIndex<T>: ForwardIndexType {
    let node: ListNode<T>

    func successor() -> ListIndex<T> {
        guard let next = node.box?.unbox.next
            else { fatalError("attempt to advance past end") }
        return ListIndex(node: next)
    }
}

func == <T>(lhs: ListIndex<T>, rhs: ListIndex<T>) -> Bool {
    switch (lhs.node.box, rhs.node.box) {
    case (nil,nil): return true
    case (_?,nil),(nil,_?): return false
    case let (x,y): return x === y
    }
}

struct List<T>: CollectionType {
    typealias Index = ListIndex<T>
    var startIndex: Index
    var endIndex: Index { return ListIndex(node: ListNode()) }
    subscript(idx: Index) -> T {
        guard let element = idx.node.box?.unbox.element
            else { fatalError("index out of bounds") }
        return element
    }
}
```

(no need to implement `generate()` – you get an indexing generator “for free” in 2.0 by implementing `CollectionType`)

You now have a fully functioning collection:

```
// in practice you would add methods to List such as
// conforming to ArrayLiteralConvertible or init from 
// another sequence
let list = List(startIndex: ListIndex(node: nodes))

list.first  // 3
for x in list { print(x) }  // prints 3 2 1
```

Now all of this code looks pretty disgusting for two reasons.

One is because box gets in the way, and `indirect` is much better as the compiler sorts it all out for you under the hood. But it’s doing something similar.

The other is that structs are not a good solution to this. Enums are much better. In fact the code is *really* using an enum – that’s what Optional is. Only instead of `nil` (i.e. `Optional.None`), it would be better to have a `End` case for the end of the linked list. This is what we are using it for.

For more of this kind of stuff you could check out [these](http://airspeedvelocity.net/2015/07/22/a-persistent-tree-using-indirect-enums-in-swift/) [posts](http://airspeedvelocity.net/2015/07/26/linked-lists-enums-value-types-and-identity/).

Comment: Great answer! But do you found also a workaround for a generic `BinaryTreeIndex` which would work on every `BinaryTreeType`?

Comment: First of all thanks for your thorough explanation! Even though I'm quite familiar with the described concepts. ;) Your answer however does not address my actual question (see the title), imo. Just as your  `List<T>` and `ListIndex<T>` are both specialized on a third type `T` (which is rather trivial, if I may say so), not on each other.

Comment: See my `BinaryTree` example: `BinaryTreeIndex` holds a stack/path of nodes (which themselves, due to their recursive nature, are full-fledged `BinaryTree`s) for efficient traversal (I could solve the dependency cycle my using a `left`/`right`-based path description, but that would require an `O(logn)` for accessing an index, instead of `O(1)`, leading to an amortized traversal complexity of `O(n log n)` instead of `O(n)`). Also as @Qbyte correctly noted I'd prefer an `Index` type that can be generalized on any type of `BinaryTreeType`.

Comment: Apropos your post on `indirect enum`: I too just finished (after fighting with this: https://openradar.appspot.com/21961187) a fully working implementation of `RBTree` (as well as `AVLTree`) based on Okasaki's book. So reading your post my first thought was "Damn, he beat me to it!" ;) Great article, btw!